En javascript sumando elementos repetidos he utilizado una función usando diccionarios, pero no puedo convertirlo para utilizando con arrays
Buscando sobre sumar elementos repetidos de arrays llegué a una consulta que me ayudó a realizarlo, solo que el ejemplo utiliza diccionarios y me funciona mejor arrays. He intentando entender y convertirlo y realmente me supera.


const bodyDict = [
    {articulo_id: 921, articulo: "Audifonos", unidades: 6},
    {articulo_id: 921, articulo: "Audifonos", unidades: 4},
    {articulo_id: 921, articulo: "Audifonos", unidades: 1},
    {articulo_id: 139, articulo: "Teclado", unidades: 1},
    {articulo_id: 139, articulo: "Teclado", unidades: 2},
    {articulo_id: 139, articulo: "Teclado", unidades: 5},
    {articulo_id: 921, articulo: "Audifonos", unidades: 5},
    {articulo_id: 139, articulo: "Teclado", unidades: 6},
    {articulo_id: 139, articulo: "Teclado", unidades: 1},
    {articulo_id: 20, articulo: "Pendrive", unidades: 5},
    {articulo_id: 20, articulo: "Pendrive", unidades: 6},
    {articulo_id: 20, articulo: "Pendrive", unidades: 4},
    {articulo_id: 15, articulo: "CD Rom", unidades: 21},
    {articulo_id: 20, articulo: "Pendrive", unidades: 9}
  ];

combina_duplicados_dict(bodyDict);

function combina_duplicados_dict(tbl) {
var a = 0;
const dictSinDuplicados = tbl.reduce((acumulador, valorActual) => {
  const se_repite = acumulador.find(elemento => elemento.articulo_id === valorActual.articulo_id);

  if (se_repite) {
    return acumulador.map((elemento) => {
      if (elemento.articulo_id === valorActual.articulo_id) {
        return {
          ...elemento,
          unidades: elemento.unidades + valorActual.unidades
        }
      }
      return elemento;
    });
  }

  return [...acumulador, valorActual];
}, []);

console.log(dictSinDuplicados);

}



La parte que realmente no puedo convertir es:
return {
...elemento,
unidades: elemento.unidades + valorActual.unidades
}
Gracias de antemano y si pudieran explicarme esas líneas en el return me ayudaria mucho porque no las entiendo
Agrego:
Quiero poder utilizar arrays así:
const body = [
    [921,"Audifonos",6],
    [921,"Audifonos",4],
    [921,"Audifonos",1],
    [139,"Teclado",1],
    [139,"Teclado",2],
    [139,"Teclado",5],
    [921,"Audifonos",5],
    [139,"Teclado",6],
    [139,"Teclado",1],
    [20,"Pendrive",5],
    [20,"Pendrive",6],
    [20,"Pendrive",4],
    [15,"CD Rom",21],
    [20,"Pendrive",9]
  ];

Por ejemplo quiero cambiar la función para poder usar
if (elemento[0] === valorActual[0])
en lugar de
if (elemento.articulo_id === valorActual.articulo_id)

No entendí bien. Puedes dar un ejemplo del resultado esperado?

ya lo edité con lo que quiero

Si te entendí bien, lo que quieres es que los elementos de tu arreglo sean arreglos en lugar de diccionarios. Aunque sugiero usar un diccionario o un Map para agruparlos más fácilmente y usar Object.values para obtener un arreglo de los valores. Así:


const bodyDict = [
    [921, "Audifonos", 6],
    [921, "Audifonos", 4],
    [921, "Audifonos", 1],
    [139, "Teclado", 1],
    [139, "Teclado", 2],
    [139, "Teclado", 5],
    [921, "Audifonos", 5],
    [139, "Teclado", 6],
    [139, "Teclado", 1],
    [20, "Pendrive", 5],
    [20, "Pendrive", 6],
    [20, "Pendrive", 4],
    [15, "CD Rom", 21,],
    [20, "Pendrive", 9],
  ];

const resultado = bodyDict.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const id = item[0];
    if (id in acc) {
        const fila = acc[id];
        fila[2] += item[2];
    }
    else {
        acc[id] = item;
    }
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(resultado));




Muchas gracias  @Mateo, es lo que necesito.

@C.Javier me alegra que te haya servido mi respuesta.
